# Loading environment vars on sudo -u

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python

I have a user named `www-app` and it has some environment vars set on its `.bashrc` file. Now from another user, say `ubuntu` how can I ran `sudo -u www-app python script.py` and will load all the environment variables of the user `www-app`?

So inside my script I can access something like:

```
import os
print os.environ['MY_VAR']
```

Comment: Did you uh...try it?

Comment: @NathanC yep, and didn't work that's why I'm asking for help if there's a way?

Comment: In the man page for sudo there is a lot of information about environment vars and how and when login shells are used, and their variables thus accessible. Start there.

Comment: The mnemonic page for sudoers is your friend too.

Comment: Upvoting the question because it has an answer that is massively useful, and was the top google result. So definitely doesn't deserve to be in the minus figures

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `sudo -i`:

[The ‑i (simulate initial login) option runs the shell specified by the password database entry of the target user as a login shell. This means that login-specific resource files such as .profile or .login will be read by the shell.](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudo.man.html)

And you can specify a command to run, as usual.

Comment: How did I not know of `sudo -i -u` until now!? You're a star! http://images.clipartpanda.com/gold-star-clipart-ncXnGRBcB.jpeg

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute a shell as the target user and have the shell start the eventual script:

```
sudo -u www-app bash -ic "python script.py"
```

Comment: Thanks but I just tried it and still not working:
`sudo -u www-app sh -c "python -c 'import os; print \"\n\".join(os.environ.keys())'"`

Comment: @Marconi Bash needs to be invoked as `bash` and with `-i` for it to read `.bashrc` (see edit).